# AppStore, why app icon is distorted in web version?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Since last update icon is stretched in weird way in the web version of Appstore. I didn't change my icons already two releases. In mobile version icon is correct, so problem only with the web version
[image: Xcode:]

[image: Appstore]

Answer (score 1):

hahaha, It's interesting, so I check up this page's source code.

the HTML show this photo is below:

```
<picture id="ember145" class="we-artwork ember-view product-hero__artwork we-artwork--fullwidth we-artwork--ios-app-icon" data-test-product-hero-artwork="">
          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/230x0w.webp 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/460x0w.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 1069px)" type="image/webp">

          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/230x0w.png 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/460x0w.png 2x" media="(min-width: 1069px)" type="image/png">

          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/217x0w.webp 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/434x0w.webp 2x" media="(min-width: 735px)" type="image/webp">

          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/217x0w.png 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/434x0w.png 2x" media="(min-width: 735px)" type="image/png">

          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/246x0w.webp 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/492x0w.webp 2x" type="image/webp">

          <source class="we-artwork__source" srcset="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/246x0w.png 1x, https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/492x0w.png 2x" type="image/png">
</picture>
```

when load this page with Chrome, `https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/230x0w.webp`, this url will be used,  and it is wrong image

and

when load this page with Safari,

`https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple124/v4/6c/64/15/6c64153a-bfb8-f201-ad96-6b7a7ce47505/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-8-0-85-220.png/246x0w.png`, this url will be used, and it normal image.

So I think that this page has a browser compatibility issue about how to show right app icon. You can contact Apple to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this bug to Apple