# App store icon triplicated (repeated three times)

Tags: ios, google-chrome, app-store, app-store-connect, appicon

recently we noticed that our [app store icon](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/acuity-schedule-admin/id1179146771) was triplicated,
here's what we set in our `AppAssets.xcassets`:

[image: AppAssets icon]

and here's what we end up with in the app store:

[image: app store icon]

it's triplicated, and it doesn't make any sense.

I checked the icon we pass, it's a 1024x1024 png file.

That seems to only be happening on **chrome**, and not on **Safari**.

What's going on?

thanks

Comment: Check the answer below, although it is partial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465079/appstore-why-app-icon-is-distorted-in-web-version

Comment: looks like your issue got solved, did you make any change?

Comment: It got solved, it was probably an apple CDN issue